# Error al instalar angular cli

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

Como pueden ver este es el error que me genera al querer instalar angular/cli:

> npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for http://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ENETUNREACH: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ENETUNREACH 151.101.0.162:80
>   npm WARN registry Using stale package data from http://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
>   npm ERR! code ENETUNREACH
>   npm ERR! errno ENETUNREACH
>   npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/postcss-discard-empty failed, reason: connect ENETUNREACH 151.101.192.162:80

Con el siguiente comando:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

Mi equipo tiene las siguiente características:

> sistema operativo es **arch linux**, 
>   **kernel 4.9.40-1-lts**, 
>   versión de node: v8.2.1
>  
>   versión de npm: 5.0.3

he podido instalarlo en windows y en fedora, asi que descarto que sea la red la que genere el problema

Comment: Buscando en google sale una web en la que hablan de la conexión a internet. Realmente el error te dice que no puede alcanzar el host **151.101.192.162**, intenta hacerle un ping y mira si responde

Comment: si responde haciendo un ping a **151.101.192.162** y **151.101.0.162**

Comment: Una ultima prueba si pones esas dos ips en el navegador te dice algo ? O no carga la pagina ?

Comment: Cierto me da este error Fastly error: unknown domain: 151.101.0.162. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.

Comment: Mirate esto: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dns-graceful-stack-switch hablan de ipv4 deshabilitado ... tal vez sea la configuracion de tu equipo, en ultima instancia abreles una incidencia